# Calculating mean across multiple axes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose

```py
inp = np.random.randint(1,500,size=(1, 2, 5, 5))
```

The output is:

```
array([[[[ 58, 223, 150, 287,  56],
         [ 59,  19, 436, 441, 299],
         [194,  79, 133,  19, 113],
         [242, 497, 494,  54,   6],
         [ 57, 382, 123, 114,  40]],

        [[170, 482, 464,  78, 429],
         [ 97, 445, 129, 319, 181],
         [370, 413, 304, 177, 215],
         [  4, 279, 366,  66,  65],
         [260, 375, 492, 282, 277]]]])
```

And now if I do

```py
np.sum(inp,axis=(2,3))
```

I get

```
array([[4575, 6739]])
```

I know that the column and the row are axes 0 and 1 respectively, but I have seen many places where the axes are passed as a tuple. I do not get how the output dimensions are calculated in such cases and along which axes or combination of axes it happens. Can I please get some light on this?

Comment: That is equal to `np.sum(np.sum(inp,2),axis=2)` sum one time reduce one dimension .

Comment: The result is a (1,2) array, the first two dimensions of the original (1,2,5,5).  In these sum/mean/max kind of operations, the specified axes 'disappear'.

Comment: `np.sum(inp,axis=(2,3),keepdims=True).shape` may also help visualize the operation.  And in your case the initial size 1 dimension might be confusing.

Comment: @hpaulj I got your first comment, that makes sense: that whichever axes you specify, those axes "disappear" and the remaining axes are the shape of the result but what decides the values in the remaining axes? Like NaN has described below, what decides the values in the result? Like for example, 'np.mean(a, axis=(2,3))' in NaN 's reply

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to use a sequence of random integers to figure out what is going on, I usually would recommend generating a pattern for testing.

```
shp = (1, 2, 3, 4)

a = np.arange(np.prod(shp)).reshape(shp)

a
Out[3]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

        [[12, 13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18, 19],
         [20, 21, 22, 23]]]])

np.mean(a, axis=(0,1))
Out[4]: 
array([[ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
       [10., 11., 12., 13.],
       [14., 15., 16., 17.]])

np.mean(a, axis=(1,2))
Out[5]: array([[10., 11., 12., 13.]])

np.mean(a, axis=(2,3))
Out[6]: array([[ 5.5, 17.5]])
```

From there you can remove the axis that may be confusing what you are expecting and re-examine

```
a = a.squeeze()

np.mean(a, axis=(0,1))
Out[8]: array([10., 11., 12., 13.])

np.mean(a, axis=(1,2))
Out[9]: array([ 5.5, 17.5])
```